# Tracking WordPress page visits by editor?

Tags: wordpress

Most page visit counters count page visits on the page.

How could a WordPress counter count by user (the user who wrote the post).

Further, WP seems to make a record of the person who edits and clicks "publish" on a post. How could a counter count by the people who clicked "publish"?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand...Can you create a hypothetical scenario? Which page visits do you want to track?

Comment: For example, my hypothetical simplified site has 4 articles published. User1 and User 2 wrote 2 articles each:<br/><br/>
User 1 - COUNT (visits)<br/> 
ArticleA - 60 <br/> 
ArticleB - 70<br/> 
TOTAL: 130<br/>
User 2 - COUNT<br/> 
ArticleC - 600<br/> 
ArticleD - 700<br/> 
TOTAL: 1300<br/>
<br/> 
There are also 2 editors (who clicked the "publish" button after editing the Users' work:<br/> <br/> 
EditorX - COUNT<br/> 
ArticleA - 60<br/> 
ArticleB - 70<br/> 
ArticleC - 600<br/> 
TOTAL: 730<br/> <br/> 
EditorY - COUNT<br/> 
ArticleD - 700<br/> 
TOTAL: 700<br/>
<br/>

Answer (score 0):

All the Posts, Pages and Custom post types are stored in `wp_posts` table with there with User ID(Every user has its own unique ID) in `post_author` field. You can fetch users information from there.

Besides that if you want to know how many times publish button clicked then use `save_meta` hook to add the counter.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp_987977987_publish_counter', 99 );
function wp_987977987_publish_counter( $post_id ) {

    // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $pp_counter = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_post_publish_counter', true );
    if( empty($pp_counter) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_post_publish_counter', 1 );
    }
    else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_post_publish_counter', $pp_counter+1 );
    }
}
```

This will update counter everytime when user click on publish button. And will fetched with the particular post/page.

Take a look on: [save_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

Comment: Thanks Jogesh, I would actually like to record not how many times "Publish" was clicked, but rather the pageviews organized by the editorUser who clicked publish on the articles they worked on (edited+published).